# pick by index in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose two arrays

```
ind = 
array([[1, 3, 2, 4, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 2, 4],
       [3, 4, 2, 0, 1]])

x =
array([[[24, 97, 28, 57, 59],
        [97, 67, 94, 77, 50],
        [56, 89, 25, 55, 76],
        [88, 21,  1, 50, 24]],

       [[54, 83, 64, 81, 12],
        [89, 49, 15, 26, 97],
        [94, 97, 32, 55, 79],
        [24, 63, 63, 15, 40]],

       [[41, 99, 84, 64, 21],
        [12,  9, 85, 43, 28],
        [75, 98, 48, 10,  0],
        [93, 94, 37, 22, 63]]])
```

I want to reorder second array according to first array.(first array is the index)

So, maybe the result will be like below.

```py
array([[[97, 57, 28, 59, 24], 
        [67, 77, 94, 50, 97],
        [89, 55, 25, 76, 56],
        [21, 50,  1, 24, 88]],

       [[54, 83, 81, 64, 12],
        [89, 49, 26, 15, 97],
        [94, 97, 55, 32, 79],
        [24, 63, 15, 63, 40]],

       [[64, 21, 84, 41, 99],
        [43, 28, 85, 12,  9],
        [10,  0, 48, 75, 98],  
        [22, 63, 37, 93, 94]]])
# x[0]s are reordered by ind[0] and so on.
```

And is this possible with [np.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy using `take_along_axis`:

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(x, ind[:, None, :], 2)
array([[[97, 57, 28, 59, 24],
        [67, 77, 94, 50, 97],
        [89, 55, 25, 76, 56],
        [21, 50,  1, 24, 88]],

       [[54, 83, 81, 64, 12],
        [89, 49, 26, 15, 97],
        [94, 97, 55, 32, 79],
        [24, 63, 15, 63, 40]],

       [[64, 21, 84, 41, 99],
        [43, 28, 85, 12,  9],
        [10,  0, 48, 75, 98],
        [22, 63, 37, 93, 94]]])
```

If you are on pre 1.15 numpy, you can do:

```
>>> m,n,k = x.shape
>>> m,n,k = np.ogrid[:m, :n, :k]
>>> x[m,n,ind[:, None, :]]
array([[[97, 57, 28, 59, 24],
        [67, 77, 94, 50, 97],
        [89, 55, 25, 76, 56],
        [21, 50,  1, 24, 88]],

       [[54, 83, 81, 64, 12],
        [89, 49, 26, 15, 97],
        [94, 97, 55, 32, 79],
        [24, 63, 15, 63, 40]],

       [[64, 21, 84, 41, 99],
        [43, 28, 85, 12,  9],
        [10,  0, 48, 75, 98],
        [22, 63, 37, 93, 94]]])
```

Comment: This solution is good! but I’m using numpy 1.14 which does not support `take_along_axis`... (`axis` parameter in `take` function looks very different with `take_along_axis` function)